# Applying indicator on HTML table using CSS3

Tags: html, css

I'm using html to build an table,

This table is applied as navigation bar, and I'm trying to add css3 animation to add creativity to the navigation bar, so I'm using this code, yet I can't figure it out why the animation is appearing partially.
Basically the animation should show 2 dots once you hover the child, one above the other in different colors, yet one dot only appears and same color for each `'li child'` in the table.

How can I add 2 dots animation while hovering child in the menu? Each child will show different colors.

CodePen
https://codepen.io/yotking789/pen/JjoJYvE

```css
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.logo {
  float: left;
}
/* ~~ Top Navigation Bar ~~ */

#navigation-container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 70px;
}

.navigation-bar {
  background-color: #352d2f;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
}
.navigation-bar img{
float:left;
margin-top: -65px
}
.navigation-bar ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  transform: translate(0);
}

.navigation-bar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  display: inline;
}

.navigation-bar li a {
  display: inline;
  color: #949494;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  line-height: 70px;
  transition: 0.2s ease color;
}

#menu {
  float: right;
}

ul li a:before, ul li a:after
{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: 0.2s ease transform;
}

ul li a:before
{
    top: 0;
    left: 10px;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
}

ul li a:after
{
    top: 5px;
    left: 18px;
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px
}

ul li a:nth-child(1):before
{
    background-color: yellow;
}

ul li a:nth-child(1):after
{
    background-color: red;
}

ul li a:nth-child(2):before
{
    background-color: #00e2ff;
}

ul li a:nth-child(2):after
{
    background-color: #89ff00;
}

ul li a:nth-child(3):before
{
    background-color: purple;
}

ul li a:nth-child(3):after
{
    background-color: palevioletred;
}
ul li a:nth-child(4):before
{
    background-color: Grey;
}

ul li a:nth-child(4):after
{
    background-color: white;
}

ul li a:hover
{
    color: #fff;
}

ul li a:hover:before, nav a:hover:after
{
    transform: scale(1);
}

ul li a:nth-child(1):hover ~ #indicator
{
    background: linear-gradient(130deg, yellow, red);
}

ul li a:nth-child(2):hover ~ #indicator
{
    left: 34%;
    background: linear-gradient(130deg, #00e2ff, #89ff00);
}

ul li a:nth-child(3):hover ~ #indicator
{
    left: 70%;
    background: linear-gradient(130deg, purple, palevioletred);
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-bar">


<div id="navigation-container">

  <img src="images/logo.png">

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Get in Touch</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think your using a `nav a` somewhere (line 133) in your css instead of `ul li`...?

Comment: I did, but it caused me trouble so I switched to ul li

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check following code, nth-child should be 'li' not for 'a',

```css
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.logo {
  float: left;
}
/* ~~ Top Navigation Bar ~~ */

#navigation-container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 70px;
  position: relative;
}

.navigation-bar {
  background-color: #352d2f;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
}
.navigation-bar img{
float:left;
margin-top: -65px
}
.navigation-bar ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  transform: translate(0);
}

.navigation-bar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  display: inline;
}

.navigation-bar li a {
  display: inline;
  color: #949494;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  line-height: 70px;
  transition: 0.2s ease color;
  position:relative;
}

#menu {
  float: right;
}

ul li a:before, ul li a:after
{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: 0.2s ease transform;
}

ul li a:before
{
    top: 0;
    left: 10px;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
}

ul li a:after
{
    top: 5px;
    left: 18px;
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px
}

ul li:nth-child(1) a:before
{
    background-color: yellow;
}

ul li:nth-child(1) a:after
{
    background-color: red;
}

ul li:nth-child(2) a:before
{
    background-color: #00e2ff;
}

ul li:nth-child(2) a:after
{
    background-color: #89ff00;
}

ul li:nth-child(3) a:before
{
    background-color: purple;
}

ul li:nth-child(3) a:after
{
    background-color: palevioletred;
}
ul li:nth-child(4) a:before
{
    background-color: Grey;
}

ul li:nth-child(4) a:after
{
    background-color: white;
}

ul li a:hover
{
    color: #fff;
}

ul li a:hover:before, ul li a:hover:after
{
    transform: scale(1);
}

ul li:nth-child(1) a:hover ~ #indicator
{
    background: linear-gradient(130deg, yellow, red);
}

ul li:nth-child(2) a:hover ~ #indicator
{
    left: 34%;
    background: linear-gradient(130deg, #00e2ff, #89ff00);
}

ul li:nth-child(3) a:hover ~ #indicator
{
    left: 70%;
    background: linear-gradient(130deg, purple, palevioletred);
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-bar">


<div id="navigation-container">

  <img src="images/logo.png">

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Get in Touch</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.logo {
  float: left;
}
/* ~~ Top Navigation Bar ~~ */

#navigation-container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 70px;
}

.navigation-bar {
  background-color: #352d2f;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
}
.navigation-bar img{
float:left;
margin-top: -65px
}
.navigation-bar ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  transform: translate(0);
}

.navigation-bar li {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  display: inline;
}

.navigation-bar li a {
  display: inline;
  color: #949494;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  line-height: 70px;
  transition: 0.2s ease color;
}

#menu {
  float: right;
}

ul li a:before, ul li a:after
{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: 0.2s ease transform;
}

ul li a:before
{
    top: 0;
    left: 10px;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
}

ul li a:after
{
    top: 5px;
    left: 18px;
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px
}

ul li:nth-child(1) a:before
{
    background-color: yellow;
}

ul li:nth-child(1) a:hover:after
{
    background-color: red;
}

ul li:nth-child(2) a:before
{
    background-color: #00e2ff;
}

ul li:nth-child(2) a:hover:after
{
    background-color: #89ff00;
}

ul li:nth-child(3) a:before
{
    background-color: purple;
}

ul li:nth-child(3) a:hover:after
{
    background-color: palevioletred;
}
ul li:nth-child(4) a:before
{
    background-color: Grey;
}

ul li:nth-child(4) a:hover:after
{
    background-color: white;
}

ul li:nth-child(5) a:before
{
    background-color: #9c27b0;
}

ul li:nth-child(5) a:hover:after
{
    background-color: #ff5722;
}

ul li a:hover
{
    color: #fff;
}

ul li a:hover:before, nav a:hover:after
{
    transform: scale(1);
}

ul li a:nth-child(1):hover ~ #indicator
{
    background: linear-gradient(130deg, yellow, red);
}

ul li a:nth-child(2):hover ~ #indicator
{
    left: 34%;
    background: linear-gradient(130deg, #00e2ff, #89ff00);
}

ul li a:nth-child(3):hover ~ #indicator
{
    left: 70%;
    background: linear-gradient(130deg, purple, palevioletred);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <title>My Portfolio</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navigation-bar">


    <div id="navigation-container">

      <img src="images/logo.png">

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Get in Touch</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```